# Geonode pyCSW additional elements from ressourceBase in new schema

Tags: geonode, pycsw

On

- Ubuntu 14.04
- geonode 2.4
- pyCSW 1.10

I´m trying to create a new schema as [plugin](http://docs.pycsw.org/en/2.0.2/outputschemas.html) based on Dublin Core. This new schema should present additional elements. Therefore I´ve extended Geonodes Base Models with additional fields:
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/2.4.x/geonode/base/models.py#L237

And added my fields in local mappings https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/2.4.x/geonode/catalogue/backends/pycsw_local_mappings.py

Unfortunately after reading the pycsw documentation I´m stuck finding a start for the plugin. Maybe one could outline the steps that are needed to create a plugin based on Dublin Core with add additional fields from geonode ressource_base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the requirement here is for a new outputschema (metadata format).

In the pycsw/GeoNode workflow, you will need to make the following updates:

- Implement your new outputschema in pycsw/plugins/outputschemas as per the [plugin docs](http://docs.pycsw.org/en/2.0.2/outputschemas.html).  I would start by copying the Atom implementation https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/pycsw/plugins/outputschemas/atom.py (as, say, `python/plugins/outputschemas/fooschema.py`)
- add the new outputschema to GeoNode:

  - add your new outputschema to `METADATA_FORMATS` in https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/cea5011c2f735e83005bea013fa784034736d057/geonode/catalogue/backends/generic.py#L37
  - add your new outputschema to `self.catalogue.formats` in https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/0bef27795d637fd75cf24a436eb1bbdeb77ace83/geonode/catalogue/backends/pycsw_local.py#L62
  - finally, add your new outputschema to `DOWNLOAD_FORMATS_METADATA` in https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/03944f5b7ab7c9b42d5d8ef7daf5f46f7dc1b2d1/geonode/settings.py#L821

At this point the new outputschema will be:

- advertised in GeoNode's CSW / pycsw endpoint
- advertised as a metadata download format

There is certainly room here to make this update less painful.  Feel free to open a pycsw / GeoNode GitHub enhancement/issue

Comment: Tom, thanks a lot for your details answer. I´m managed to create a new schema unfortunately I´m stuck with the namespace. I´ve updated my answer. If this does not take to long for you maybe you could outline the steps regarding the namespace as well? thanks a million!

Comment: Good to hear! Would love to see this work!

Comment: Hi Tom, sure! Will share the link when I´m finished! May I ask you if this is the logic for Atom Export https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/1.10/pycsw/plugins/outputschemas/atom.py where can I found the logic for Dublin Core Export?

Comment: The Dublin Core serializers are in:

- https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/pycsw/ogc/csw/csw2.py#L1419 (CSW 2)
- https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/blob/master/pycsw/ogc/csw/csw3.py#L1481 (CSW 3)

Note they are not implemented within a plugin context given Dublin Core is the baseline format that any CSW must provide.